# Access user properties through a helper method in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, ruby-on-rails-4

I wrote this helper method:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  private

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end
  helper_method :current_user
end
```

To which i should be able, in my mind, to do `current_user.role == 'some role'` but when I do that it spazzes out saying "undefined method role for nil:NilClass" now does that mean the role column is empty and has nothing it in or that the user object is empty? because I assure you I am logged in, I exist in the database and .... the role field in  the database is empty how ever.

**Update** I should probably state that doing `User.role == 'admin'` works, as their is a role attribute in the database, or well column. Why can't I do .role on current_user?

Comment: The message means that `current_user` is returning `nil`. How are you handling login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this error, you can be certain that current_user is returning the value nil. So the issue isn't the method role. You should note that User.role is a class method on the model User, so it is not calling a method on one particular user. current_user.role on the other hand is an instance method for one particular user, the user that is signed in.

I would put the following right above the method that is throwing the error:

```
raise session[:user_id].inspect
```

After confirming the appropriate user_id is in the session cookie using the above method, you could also put the following at the end of your current_user helper method to confirm that a user is actually being returned:

```
raise @current_user.inspect
```

What is the logic you are using to create the session[:user_id]? Also, you may want to clear your browser cache or open an Incognito Window (in chrome it is cmd + shift + n) and go back through the sign in process of your app.